# Converting Pandas datetime attribute to integer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a CSV dataset with the 'date' attribute as follows:

> 2012-04-29
>
> 2012-04-29
>
> 2012-04-29
>
> 2012-05-05
>
> 2012-05-05
>
> Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

I want to convert the unique date values to integer values. So the first 3 values for same date '2012-04-29' become 1, the second two values for same date '2012-05-05' becomes 2 and so on.

How can I do this conversion of 'date' attribute to a new integer attribute/column say 'date_int'?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do

```
df['date'].rank(method='dense')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at factorize:

```
df['date'].factorize()[0] + 1
```